# Index outside of bounds of the array when using DataGrid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to directly bind an array to a grid view control, where I am trying to display the details on grid view control.

I have tried the below code, but it is throwing up some errors. Please help me to find proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
protected void ddlCircle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter cd;
cd = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = cd.GetAvailableData(ddlCircle.SelectedValue); 

int x, y;

DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
dt3 = cd.GetTeam();
y = dt3.Rows.Count;

x = dt.Rows.Count; 
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = cd.GetAssignTeam(x);           

string[] strArr = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
int i = 0;

testc:                            
foreach (DataRow r in dt2.Rows)
   {                
     strArr[i] = r["Team"].ToString();
     i++;
     if (i >= x - 1)
     {
        break;
     }
     if (i >= y)
     {
        goto testc;       
     }          
   }
GridView2.DataSource = strArr[i];
GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`GridView2.DataSource = strArr[i];` this Line will likely produce the error, right? It is because you incremented `i` within your final iteration to `dt2.Rows.Count + 1`

Write this

```
if (i > 0) GridView2.DataSource = strArr[i - 1];
```

as last line.

Comment: Now the error is not showing, but gridview not displaying any values.